# Sniffing Android App Data

Tags: android, security, fiddler, packet-sniffers

I've setup fiddler to sniff the data going from my Android emulator. However, it's only picking up browser requests. How do I go about picking up the data calls apps make via the device? I know they use web services, such as WhatsApp, but it won't pick anything up. Do I use something else other than fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/about.html)? It is an amazing network analyzer

Comment: I haven't in fact, I haven't even heard of it. Will this do the trick?

Comment: It is used for live capture of everything that pass through the network. I never used it for data calls apps capture, but it helps me to understand the behave of many app.